# Apps-Script post request

Tags: post, google-apps-script, http-post, urlfetch

I've been trying to pull the CA CPUC data to return information based on the CPUC#. This has been kicking my butt. Sessions and checksums are currently active in the snippet but would need to be updated to reproduce. Before I write the code to get the appropriate session data I would love to have one post request actually work as expected. Seems to work in Postman no problem but in apps script it fails every time.

I've looked at all the other Apps script Post related questions. I haven't seen any that include session info.

Pretty, please help.

```
function cpuc(input = "") {
    //input=0017;

    //if (input == "") {
        //input = ''
    //} else

    //{var num = input.toString(); }

    var formData = {
        'p_arg_checksums':'33316309586380504_F1C39724CC9F8514705A3E90B641B338',
        'p_arg_names':'15205107486571135',
        'p_arg_names':'33315885014380503',
        'p_arg_names':'33316093548380503',
        'p_arg_names':'33316309586380504',
        'p_arg_names':'14878578395513793',
        'p_flow_id':'203',
        'p_flow_step_id':'35',
        'p_instance':'5080254898961',
        'p_md5_checksum':'',
        'p_page_checksum':'C863921514D0032E5859DB0CAB79534A',
        'p_page_submission_id':'4390229111775',
        'p_request':'Submit',
        'p_t01':'PSG',
        'p_t02':'17',
        'p_t03':'',
        'p_t04':'',
        'p_t05':'-1',
    };

    var headers = {
        'Origin':'https://apps.cpuc.ca.gov',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Referer':'https://apps.cpuc.ca.gov/apex/f?p=203:35:0::NO:RP::',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
        'Cookie':'gsScrollPos=; ORA_WWV_APP_203=ORA_WWV-zjF8IrxaICg6oRrzu9Dpw6dU'
    };
    var url = 'https://apps.cpuc.ca.gov/apex/wwv_flow.accept';

    var options = {
        "method" : "post",
        "headers" : headers,
        "payload" : formData
    };


    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var text = response.getContentText();

    //extract appropriate informatoin.

    Logger.log(text);

    return text;

}
```

I also haven't had much luck parsing the HTML responses in apps script. (Extra credit).

Comment: Are you getting any response error?

Comment: What `input` are you passing it?  And, did you try it without the headers param?  Are you really sending this from the Origin `'https://apps.cpuc.ca.gov'`?

Comment: I'm getting an HTML response of "No carrier found" but I know by submitting the form manually that "17" is a valid and active CPUC carrier ID.

Comment: Here's a link to the sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPZdyHhUUOsKoTQZKmZGK64TcYioNW5lcWd9cUnLImA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: p_t02 is the input. I intended to pass input as a function but I've just been trying to get it working with a known active carrier at the moment "17". I'm sending it from Apps script so it's not inside the ca.gov domain but that doesn't seem to stop Postman from working.

Comment: Just tried without headers. Same result.

Comment: formData elements should be strings. 'p_t05' should be (e.g.) "34".  ("-1" may tell the endpoint that you forgot to select a county).  The rest of your code looks fine.  I think this is an issue of talking to their API, and not any coding error.

Comment: I would think so also, accept for the fact I had it working at some point. Also why would it work in Postman but not from the apps script?

Comment: Try moving this `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`out of the header and putting `contentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the options.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Placing project on hold. Sad day..